# $r(I) =1 \iff I =1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

> Let r(I) be defined as radical of ideal I. Then show that $r(I) =1 \iff I =1$.

Let $I=1$ then I have proved the other side as in that $x^n\in I=1$ which implies that $x=1$. On the converse let $r(I)=1$,then {$x\in A \mid x^n \in I$} =1, let $x\in I/\{1\}$ exists. But I am not able to proceed for this case.

Please help.

Comment: Is $1=(1)=A$ the whole ring, i.e., $I=1=A$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking $I$ as an ideal of ring $A$.

If $r(I)=1$, then $1_A\in r(I)$, that is, exists $n\in\mathbb Z_{>0}$ such that $1_A=(1_A)^n\in I$. Therefore $I=1$.